# $y = -2\sin(x - \pi/3):\;$minimum & maximum values?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have the following function $$y = -2\sin⁡(x-\pi/3),\quad 0\leq x\leq 2\pi$$

I know that $\sin x$ has max at $\pi/2$ and min at $3\pi/2$ but how would I use this information to find the solution to the question in the title?

Comment: Hints: Plot it. What have you learned about finding min and max functions?

Comment: Another hint: what is sin(x-pi/2) equivalent to?

Comment: What should I do about -2?

Comment: sorry, I meant put $x-\pi/2=3\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Basic trigonometry without calculus

$$\begin{align*}&\bullet\;\;\;\sin\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)=\sin\left(-\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\right)\\&\bullet\;\;\;\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)=\cos\alpha\\
&\bullet\;\;\;\sin(-x)=-\sin x\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't understand this one, what I should do with -2 in the function?

Comment: Nothing: you get $\,2\cos x\;,\;0\le x\le\frac\pi2\;$ . You know how the graph of cosine looks, right? Well, now just multiply it by two...

Comment: I have made a slight correction in the question.

Comment: That's not "slight" but a new question which, imo, you should post separatedly.

Comment: User was removed so ${+}^{+\infty}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the brute force way:
$$y' = -2\cos(x-\pi/3)= 0$$
$$\cos(x-\pi/3)=0$$
We need the argument of $\cos$ to be an odd multiple of $\pi/2$ for $\cos$ to be zero:
$$x-\pi/3 = (2n-1)\pi/2$$
$$x = n\pi-\pi/2+\pi/3 = n\pi -\pi/6$$

So, $y$ obtains maxima / minima at the points $[\pi-\pi/6,2\pi-\pi/6]$. Plug in $x$, to find which point is which.

Comment: Can you see the edit?

Comment: @user2082191 - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $b=x-\frac {\pi}{2}$ . Then we have $y=-2 \sin b$ . As you said, the max and min of sine occur at $\frac {\pi}{2}$ and $\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ . So for the max, $b=\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ and for the min $b=\frac {\pi}{2}$ (it's flipped because you have a $-2$ in front). Since  $b=x-\frac {\pi}{2}$ , for the max $x-\frac {\pi}{2}=\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ $\to$ $x=2\pi$ , and you do the same for the min. And of course you can add or subtract $2n \pi$ from the answer to get infinately many other answers.

Comment: Can you please clarify this,  x−π2=3π2 → x=2π, I kinda doubt this step

Comment: We said $b=x-\frac {\pi}{2}$ . Then we also said $b=\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ . If both $\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ and $x-\frac {\pi}{2}$ are equal to the same thing, then they are equal to each other. Hope this helps

Comment: If $x-\frac {\pi}{2}=\frac {3 \pi}{2}$ , we can add $\frac {\pi}{2}$ to both sides in order to solve for $x$

Comment: Can you see the edit now? I have made a slight correction.

Comment: Oh ok. Well we can use the same method. We set $b=x-\frac {\pi}{3}$ .  Since the max and min of $\sin b$ occur at $\frac {\pi}{2}$ and $\frac {3\pi}{2}$ , we want $b$ to equal one of these. Using the same one as before (the max), we set $b=\frac {3\pi}{2}$ , and since $b=x-\frac {\pi}{3}$ , we have $x-\frac {\pi}{3}=\frac {3\pi}{2}$ . Adding $\frac {\pi}{3}$ to both sides, we get $x=\frac {11\pi}{6}$ , of course plus or minus $2n\pi$

Comment: Actually sorry, not plus or minus $2n\pi$ because your $x$ is restricted to be between $0$ and $2\pi$

Comment: Now I have another question, what happens to -2 in the question?

Comment: Ok I forgot to answer the second part of the question, which is the $y$ value. Since we know that the maximum occurs at $x=\frac {11\pi}{6}$ , then to find the $y$ value we just plug this in:

Comment: We get $y=-2 \sin ((\frac {11\pi}{6})-\frac {\pi}{3})$ , or $y=-2 \sin (\frac {3 \pi}{2})$ , which simplifies to positive 2. This is where the $-2$ came in. Not the that $-2$ only affected the $y$ value, but the $x$ value was not affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

the function has maximum when $\sin(x - π/3)$ is minimum ie,

$\sin(x - π/3)= -1$

or, $x - π/3= 3π/2$       ie,$x= 11π/6$   when $(2π ≤ x ≤ 2π)$

and, minimum at,

$\sin(x - π/3)= 1$

or,$(x - π/3)= π/2$       ie, $x =5π/6$   when $(2π ≤ x ≤ 2π)$

similarly, we can find the general solution